# UPDATE em massa linha e linha | SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

EXEMPLO:

Tenho duas tabelas X e Y
onde tabela X contem as seguintes informações
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tabela Y
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

To tentando realizar um update na coluna cod_cliente da tabela X, porém esse update deve preencher a coluna com o valor de cdcli da tabela Y, de acordo com o respectivo CNPJ.